# .NET SQL connection code is blocking all other connections

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

Apologies if the subject does not accurately reflect my exact issues, I'm struggling to explain the issue I'm having, although it seems quite straight-forward.

I've built a simple "db helper" class which executes sql statements for me, given some parameters, etc. Here's the code block:

```
public DataSet selectSprocData(string sprocName, SqlParameter[] parameterArray, out int returnValue)
    {

        //processes the specified Select stored procedure based on parameter array provided;
        //this is the only place anywhere in the application we will do a simple SELECT using a sproc.

        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyServer"].ToString()))
        {
            cn.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sprocName, cn);
            adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddRange(parameterArray);
            SqlParameter retValParam = adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@RETURN_VALUE", SqlDbType.Int);
            retValParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 600;
            adapter.Fill(dataset);
            returnValue = (int)retValParam.Value;
            adapter.Dispose();
            cn.Close();
        }

        return dataset;
    }
```

When I take a long-running sproc and execute it within SSMS it will run and eventually time out. Meanwhile I can open another query window in SSMS and execute any other select or queries against my db.

Now, when I call this sproc through my web-app using the code-block above it, the page will spin and load and load until eventually (a few minutes later) the process will time out.

However, during this web-based call I can NOT open any other window and execute any other UI functions that use the same db-code to call other sprocs.

Essentially, one user executing a sproc/function from the UI which takes long seems to be blocking everyone else from doing anything on my app.

I understand that first and foremost I need to have better queries that don't time out, but is there something I'm missing or not doing right in .net/c# that would be causing all other connections or command attempts to be blocked until the other one has finished or timed out?

My web.config connectionstring has no special parameters, simply:

```
Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Password=xxxx;Initial Catalog=db_live;Data Source=my.host.com"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Andre, are you saying that you cannot view any other pages in the site (like, even in different browser tabs), or are you saying that just the one page instance that you are looking at, the one which is executing the SQL command, is hung?

Comment: @udog: *"Andre, are you saying that you cannot view any other pages in the site (like, even in different browser tabs"* Yes, that's what he's saying. In fact, he's saying different users on completely different machines are blocked: *"Essentially, one user executing a sproc/function from the UI which takes long seems to be blocking everyone else from doing anything on my app."*

Comment: @Andre How complex is the query?  Is it possible it is putting a database lock of some sort that prevents other concurrent queries to DB?  Can you take a look at state of DB and see that other queries are queued or running - this will tell you if queries at least make it to DB concurrently or if code is serializing access somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really compare a Windows Application (SQL Management Studio) to an ASP.NET web app (running in IIS)

ALl of your ASP.NET code is running on a single thread, so that thread has to wait for the  database code to complete, which blocks all everything else, until it's done.

Use an ASP.NET Update panel to perform your long running stored procedure and UI binding.

[ASP.NET Update Panel](http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updatepanel-control)

Comment: Just trying to simplify the answer. Updated it to be more precise.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies! I'm using jquery/ajax calls from the UI to call some of these queries and update parts of the page on response. So to clarify, I need to look at asynch execution of my sql commands?

Comment: How are you calling your DB layer from jQuery/AJAX? Is it a WCF or Web Api Service?

Comment: I call the db using the exact code in my question above, and i have simple c# classes that call that method

Comment: What i mean, is how is that code being called? Is it in the code behind in OnLoad? When a button is clicked?

Comment: *"All of your ASP.NET code is running on a single thread, so that thread has to wait for the database code to complete, which blocks all everything else, until it's done."* All of the code **for that request**, but IIS uses a pool of service threads (worker processes, actually, I think) in the application pool, right? So other requests coming in from other clients should be serviced by those other threads.

Comment: Right, which is why i am asking how this code is being called. If it's in the same request, then it's going to block. If it's not, then something else is up.